# How to come up a name for an underwater (e.g. Mermaid) ceremony?

Tags: creative-writing

I need help finding ceremony names that would suit underwater ceremonies. I've looked at several name generators and thought they wouldn't work underwater. I've also thought about the "Coral Reef Ceremony," which now sounds stupid and juvenile, but it's the only thing I can think of that's 'underwater' themed.

The ceremony celebrates her first trip away from home alone for the first time; as soon as she's 15, she gets to go anywhere past the Coral Reef where her father's castle is located, including the surface, as long as she's not seen.

Comment: We can't come up with the name for you, but we can give you advice on how to come up with the name yourself.

Answer (score 13):

There is a difference between how outside observers (e.g. ethnologists) name a ceremony and how the members of a community call it themselves. Outsiders often use descriptive names like "Coral Reef Ceremony" or "Walkabout", describing where the ceremony takes place, its elements, or what it is thought to be about, while insiders usually use more abstract terms such as Bar Mitzvah (meaning "to subject the community member to the law"), Communion ("union between the community member and Christ"), Confirmation ("public confession of faith"), etc.

What I would do in your case is

1. design the faith of the people that perform your ritual and
2. work out what that ritual signifies for them. Then,
3. from within the perspective of their worldview, try and brainstorm terms that they might use to name that ritual.
4. If you want, make up a language for them and translate that term to their language. But I'm not sure underwater languages can be well represented using Latin letters, so I probably wouldn't attempt this final step.

You might want to do some research into rites of passage to get an idea what meaning they have and how they are named in the real world. Here is a possible starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Rites_of_passage. But make sure you look at the terms the peoples use themselves!

As a side note, many ceremonial terms may sound "stupid" when you hear them for the first time, but habituation (we grow up with them) and the meaning they have (for us individually and in our community) make the terms feel natural, obvious, and self-evident. Readers, too, grow accustomed to terms over the course of a book.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more creative means of making a name, try to use abbreviations instead of full words (such as, in your case, CRC for "Coral Reef Ceremony").

Or, you could just lightly hint at the ceremony name, have a character say that in your case, say that it does sound stupid, etc., and focus more on what happens at the ceremony.

Maybe you can do what the many major religions do and use an older language when writing out these ceremonies, but this all depends on how long this ceremony has been running and how easily it could be interpreted.

It can be used in simpler terms, such as when the king's coronation is verbatim, which is called "The King's Coronation."

It all depends on importance, what actually happens, and how long the ceremony has been running for.